# Does whitespace before punctuation apply in all conditions?

Tags: typographie, ponctuation

According to [Unicode notes on French](http://unicode.org/udhr/n/notes_fra.html), *narrow*, *non-breaking* and *plain* spaces apply in accordance with stated punctuation rules, e.g. «NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE» before colons and plain space after:

> Corentin : Pardon, madame, pour aller à la gare, s'il vous plaît ? [[character inspector]](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=Corentin%20%3A%20Pardon%2C%20madame%2C%20pour%20aller%20%C3%A0%20la%20gare%2C%20s%27il%20vous%20pla%C3%AEt%E2%80%AF%3F)

Can I safely replace all colons in text dialogues with "narrow space + colons"? Does it depend on context?

Comment: BTW en français « espace » est féminin quand on parle de typographie. Ici il faut entendre « une demi-espace insécable » avant ces signes de ponctuation :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes before a colon, a (thin) space is always expected.

Note that before other two-stroke punctuation marks (semicolon, exclamation and question mark), when rendering the text on a system that doesn't make a difference between a thin space and a regular space (typically web pages), the norm differs between Québec and France.

The former one [tells](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=5034#:%7E:text=Le%20point%20d%27interrogation%2C%20le,sont%20pr%C3%A9c%C3%A9d%C3%A9s%20d%27aucune%20espace.) to use no space at all while in France, a regular space is expected.

More rules about spacing from the OQLF [here](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2039).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to insert a space before:

- `:` colon
- `;` semicolon
- `!` exclamation mark
- `?` question mark
- `»` right quotation mark

and a space after:

- `«` left quotation mark